# getting T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE error in PHP

Tags: php, whitespace

I am creating an App in php
in which i am getting an error on this line #

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table ( `rollnum`,'sessionid', `class`, `subject`, `theory`, `practical`, `type_of`, `term`) VALUES ('$students['rollnum']', '$session','$class','$subject['id']','$_REQUEST[$subject['id'].'_'.$students['rollnum'].'_th']','$_REQUEST[$subject['id'].'_'.$students['rollnum'].'_pr']', '$examtype', '$examsubtype')";
```

I dont knoe what's wrong with this line.
i even checked at an [online platform](http://www.meandeviation.com/tutorials/learnphp/php-syntax-check/v4/syntax-check.php).They said the same that there is error on Line #(above).
Anyone who can help me with this
Thanks

Comment: Can you paste in a few lines of code around that one?  It may be that you're opening a quote on a previous line and the quote in this one is closing it, and confusing the parser.

Comment: something funky with $_REQUEST syntax?

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) waiting to happen.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: How does the accepted post answer this question? It's suggesting an IDE, which is completely irrelevant to the problem, and does nothing to determine what the actual error is in the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to use dreamweaver or net bean that might help you to find the error at the correct place

Answer (score 3):

you likely need to surround the variables in a double quoted string with braces.

```
$string = "I want to use {$variable1} and {$variable['thisKey']}";
```

or the following, which is a little faster to run;

```
$string = 'I want to use'.$variable1.'and '.$variable['thisKey'];
```

So that should solve your immediate problem, however your query is very open to an injection which can be very bad, especially if your using `$_REQUEST` right in your query string. I'd recommend looking into preparing your query statements before running them and ensuring all the dangerous stuff is escaped.

I answered another question that includes a safe way of doing a query over [here with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320796/saving-json-string-to-mysql-database/11321173#11321173)

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your variable names with braces inside the string:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO stdexamrecord ( `rollnum`,'sessionid', `class`, `subject`, `theory`, `practical`, `type_of`, `term`) VALUES (
'${students['rollnum']}', 
'$session',
'$class',
'${subject['id']}',
' " . $_REQUEST[ $subject['id'] . '_' . $students['rollnum'] . '_th'] . "',
' " . $_REQUEST[ $subject['id'] . '_' . $students['rollnum'] . '_pr'] . "',
'$examtype', 
'$examsubtype')";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP environment had had these settings: `display_errors = On; error_reporting = E_ALL`, you would have seen:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

Like in this example:

```
$array['value'] = 'test';
echo "$array['value']";
```

It should be like that:

```
echo "".$array['value']."";
echo "{$array['value']}";
```

Anyway, you can use numeric keys:

```
$array[0] = 'test';
echo "$array[0]";
```