# Insert huge amount of data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So  I am trying to store user likes from facebook in database

```
$likes_json=json_encode($user->likes->data);
echo($likes_json);
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ','".$likes_json."', NOW())";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

"echo" prints out the expected string (of length 56000 characters)

```
[{"name":"The Next Web","category":"Website","id":"106976563522"....
```

But nothing is being stored in Database. When I change `$likes_json='some other string';` it works fines(it gets inserted in the database)

Coloumn for likes is of type "`mediumtext`"

Comment: look at this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320796/saving-json-string-to-mysql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape $likes_json using mysql_real_escape_string

Your query ends up looking like this

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ','[{"name":"The Next Web","category":"Website","id":"106976563522"}]', NOW())
```

See why that wouldn't work? What if the data contains a ' ?

Comment: Apologies. Use mysqli escaping equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The error can be escaping, but the only way to know for sure is to print the error:

```
$mysqli->query($query) or die("Error: ":$mysqli->error);
```

Escaping:

```
$likes_json=json_encode($user->likes->data);
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ','%s', NOW())";
$query = sprintf($query,$mysqli->real_escape_string($likes_json);
```